# How to link to another html page using javascript in Google Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I have a Google Script project and I am trying to link through javascript to another HTML page that is included in the project. My code is the following:

```
function doGet(e) {
  if (e.parameters.page=="page2") 
      return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("page2");
  else
      return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("page1");
}
```

**This is the command I'm now trying to open the other page with:**

```
window.location.assign(window.location.href+"?page=page2");
```

Comment: I do not know if can be because of this, but have you already tried window.localtion = `${window.location.href}?page=page2` ?

Comment: @TheMaster Thanks a lot!